# Information sources for multiple hierachy trees in a single table

Tags: database-theory, hierarchy, tree

I need some quality sources - books, websites etc. - to educate myself about putting multiple hierarchy trees in a single table using SQL.

I'm looking for some good theoretical and practical information.

Answer (score 1):

You can put multiple hierarchies in an Oracle table and query it using a hierarchical query.  See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries003.htm#SQLRF52332).

Answer (score 1):

Taken from a comment by [this user](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993):

> See [Models for Hierarchical Data](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data)
>
> It's MySQL biased but it has basic discussion about the various models and code.

Answer (score 0):

What we have done with LedgerSMB for our business reporting dimensions (each dimension is hierarchical) is to have a dimensions table, and a units table.  Each member of the units belongs to a dimension, and we define hierarchy using the self join of (parent, unit_class) references (id, unit_class).  This way we have multiple equivalent hierarchies sharing a table.